# PHP Unlink error on deletion of file with 777 permission in Ubuntu

Tags: php

1. I have a PHP code that creates a file in the /tmp directory, running
   on Ubuntu. Just after creation, I change the access of the file to
   777 using:

   ```
   chmod($file_name, 0777);
   ```

   In a different process, when I try to delete that file, I receive
   the following error:

   > Warning: unlink(/tmp/656f19ae71bdd.xml): Operation not permitted in
   > [...]

   Some additional info that may be useful:

   1. The process that creates the file is created by a crontab routine
   2. The process that is trying to delete it is started by web access
   3. The PrivateTmp config is set to false, so the file is really being created at /tmp folder
   4. The chmod command is working just fine: the file is really with 777 permission

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to disable apparmor (`apt purge apparmor`) on system or make sure php hasa allowance by apparmor

Comment: Tried disabling apparmor, didn't work.

Comment: have You restarted apache or php-fpm after disabling?

Comment: I hadn't! No I did and it worked. Thanks! However it raises me a doubt and a concern: Why? Is it safe?!

Comment: If You're only owner of system and You just run Your app and know that it just works with db and concrete set of files: yes, it's safe. Otherwise investigate how to define permissions to php process using apparmor. I mostly disable it, cause I run php-fpm process under the user and define limitations inside /home/someuser/someapp folder

Comment: I recommend You to change upload file path in php configs to avoid saving files to /tmp folder which is more preferred

Answer (score 1):

I recommend You to move upload tmp dir param to user folder which php process runs to avoid disabling security features of OS (in Your case it was apparmor).

So here is what I do:
[image: desc]

by setting `php_admin_value[upload_tmp_dir] = "/home/currentuser/tmp"`  I make sure that files uploaded by user not going to `/tmp` folder which causing permission and etc issues.